From start to finish but …… not only once!
Inspired by this post, but not quite the same!
Based on the following...
0 → ✅❌✅✅
1 → ✅✅❌
2 → ❌✅✅
3 → ❌❌✅❌❌
4 → ❌✅✅✅
5 → ❌✅✅❌
6 → ✅✅❌
7 → ✅❌✅❌✅
8 → ？？？？？
9 → ✅✅✅❌

...replace each question mark with the correct symbol.
Hint 1:

 Visual


One concern I have about questions like this is:  https://i.sstatic.net/pBWM5FAf.png

I believe the answer is

 ❌✅✅❌❌

Reason

 Basically each number is represented by its word counterpart by the crosses and ticks. The crosses represent the letters in capital that you can’t draw without taking the pen off the page and but the ticks represent the letters that can. Therefore EIGHT——>❌✅✅❌❌

